# Can I trigger an Update Panel from a Drop Down list in a User Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a user control in a master page with two drop down lists.  When the user selects an item out of either ddl, I want to load a specific user control inside an update panel on the content page. I can't figure out how to get the user control to trigger the update panel. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

**Master**

```
    <%@ Register src="toolbar.ascx" tagname="toolbar" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </div>
    <uc1:toolbar ID="toolbar1" runat="server" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**User Control**

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="toolbar.ascx.cs" Inherits="Blah.toolbar" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDesiredPage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            EnableViewState="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="goToSelectedPage">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-">DDL 1</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDesiredPageSP" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        EnableViewState="True"
        onselectedindexchanged="goToSelectedPage">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-">DDL 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Content Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" onload="UpdatePanel1_Load">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        ?????????????????????????????????
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It will depend on you telling it to use chilren as triggers (which is by default) or not.  How about posting some code so we can better help you.

Comment: Ok, I added some basic code that I hope helps express the scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the panel via the User Control you've created, you could try setting the UpdatePanel's `UpdateMode = Conditional`. Then, in your User Control's click event (or whichever event), have something like this:

```
 UpdatePanel mUpdatePanel = this.Page.Master.FindControl("upContent") as UpdatePanel;  
    if (mUpdatePanel != null)  
    {
        mUpdatePanel.Update();  
    }
    else
    {
         //update panel not found
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Since you can't access your triggers declaratively, you could add them from the code-behind. On your content page, add something like this:

```
 AsyncPostBackTrigger triggerUserControl = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
                        DropDownList ucDDL = this.Page.Master.FindControl("ddlDesiredPage") as DropDownList;
                        triggerUserControl.ControlID = ucDDL.ID;
                        triggerUserControl.EventName = "Click";

                        UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(triggerUserControl);
```

Do the same for the other DropDownList. I haven't tried this, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: Ok I see what your doing and I think it's close to what I need. The layout is switched around though. My user control is on the master page, and my updatepanel is in the web content page.

Comment: In that case, in your MasterPage code-behind (For the user control event), you could try:
`UpdatePanel mUpdatePanel = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("upContent") as UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a postback trigger to your UpdatePanel:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl..." />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: Right, but how do i find the ddl if its in a user control on my master page?