# Trying to use ASCX control for file upload inside an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ascx

So I have an `ascx` control for file upload. This control has a `FileUpload` element and an `imagebutton` in a `table`, as well as a `grid` to display the uploaded file when done.
The `grid` and the `fileupload`+`imagebutton` `table` are never visible at the same time.

The `imagebutton`'s click event is in the ascx.cs file:

```
    public void btnUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileUpload.HasFile)
            //if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUpload.FileName))
            {
                String fileName = fileUpload.FileName;// strPath.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
                String ext = fileUpload.FileName.Split('.')[1];
                Guid newFileName = Guid.NewGuid();
                string strPath = MapPath("~/importfiles/") + newFileName.ToString() + "." + ext;
                fileUpload.SaveAs(strPath);
                LoadTable(fileName);
                hfFilePath.Value = strPath;
                hfFileName.Value = fileName;
                hfMIMEType.Value = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
                hfFileGUID.Value = newFileName.ToString();
                hfFileUploaded.Value = "1";
            }
            else
            {
                grdAttachment.Visible = false;
                filePickTable.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UserInterfaceExceptionHandler.HandleException(ref ex);
        }
    }
```

On the content page, I have to test whether the control already has a file or not in order to know which view to display of the control (grid vs fileupload).

```
if (attr.ImageValue != null)
{
    //Do stuff to display grid instead of fileupload control
    PostBackTrigger newTrigger = new PostBackTrigger();
    newTrigger.ControlID = attrControl.ID;
    IssueUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(newTrigger);
}
else
{
    (attrControl.FindControl("filePickTable") as Table).Width = new Unit("200px");
    ImageButton btnUploadFile = attrControl.FindControl("btnUploadFile") as ImageButton;
    AsyncPostBackTrigger newTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    newTrigger.ControlID = btnUploadFile.ID;
    newTrigger.EventName = "Click";
    IssueUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(newTrigger);
}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that the `else` code (for when there is no file), I get the following exception:

> Could not find an event named 'Click' on associated control 'btnUploadFile' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'IssueUpdatePanel'.

The page has a `Timer` which auto refreshes the page every few seconds.

I tried looking everywhere for a solution, but to no avail.
Hopefully I have given enough information on here.

Comment: can you post your ASPX code?

Comment: @lucidgold: Do you want the mark up for the control or the page I am trying to use it on?

Comment: Well, I am trying to make sense of the "Could not find an event named 'Click'". Did you not declare it in your ASPX page? Are you sure you have it in your ASCX?

Comment: @lucidgold: Yes, the click event is in the ascx.cs file. I am creating the trigger in the aspx.cs file where I am trying to implement the control. This is the same solution that was recommended on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503093/can-i-trigger-an-update-panel-from-a-drop-down-list-in-a-user-control

Comment: On which line of code are you getting this error? And in which method does the ELSE case execute?

Comment: I tried tracing through the entire code, and this is the best stack trace I could find:   
at System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackTrigger.Initialize()
at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection.Initialize()
at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)